403 error when pushing Nuget to my organization's registry GitHub actions
I have an organization in GitHub with Free plan. I created a private repository for this organization and GitHub action to build and push my nuget package to registry.
My GitHub action code is following:
name: nuget-publish

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
    paths:
      - Package.core/**
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]
    paths:
      - Package.core/**

defaults:
  run:
    shell: pwsh

jobs:
  build:
  
    env:
      PROJECT: './Package.core/src/Package.Core.SDK/Package.Core.SDK.csproj'
      BUILD_CONFIG: 'Release'
  
    name: Build Package
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Set up .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
      with:
        dotnet-version: '8.0.x'

    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build ${{ env.PROJECT }} --configuration ${{ env.BUILD_CONFIG }}
      
    - name: Package
      run: >
        dotnet pack ${{ env.PROJECT }} --no-restore --no-build --configuration ${{ env.BUILD_CONFIG }}
        --output .
 
    - name: Publish
      run: >
        dotnet nuget push **/Package.Core.SDK.*.nupkg
        -s 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<organization-name>/index.json'
        -k ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

To create GH_PAT secret a followed next steps:

For the account I created my organization from I created personal access token with the following permissions: 
For the repository I created new Repository Secret:

After running this Github action I'm getting the following error:

warn : Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages
service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the
appropriate scopes configured.


error: Response status code does not
indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).


